# Prevent batch script from terminating upon invalid character input

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, scripting

I always have this issue when writing batch scripts. Whenever I have the script prompt the user to set a variable, if a semicolon (that's just one example) is inputted, the script will close. Is there a way to prevent it from doing so?

Example:

```
@echo off
:1
cls
echo Please enter your ID:
set /P id=
if /i %id%==119 goto Tom
if /i %id%==204 goto Brittany
if /i %id%==12 goto Shannon
if /i %id%==64 goto Jack
goto 1

:Tom
cls
echo Tom, you have to mow the lawn.
pause>nul
exit

:Brittany
cls
echo Brittany, you have to fold the laundry.
pause>nul
exit

:Shannon
cls
echo Shannon, you have to feed the dog.
pause>nul
exit

:Jack
cls
echo Jack, you have to replace the radio's capacitors.
pause>nul
exit
```

What I would see running that script:

```
C:\>myscript.bat
Please enter your ID:
asjfash;dfjlas;ldf
asjfash;dfjlas;ldf==i was unexpected at this time.
```

and the script closes.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share your failing code, follow how-to create a [mcve].

Comment: I apologize, JosefZ, I'm still new here.

Comment: Showing  _result_ is right and necessary however not sufficient; show your failing _code_ as well. Read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). Definitely, you need to escape semicolon(s) e.g. like in this example: `if /i "%varname%"=="literal;string" call :labelE`

Comment: My sincerest apologies, I've added some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Syntax : [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

> **Delimiters**
>
> Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the
>   command line up into words.
>
> Parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the
>   following are also valid delimiters:
>
> - Comma (`,`)
> - Semicolon (`;`)
> - Equals (`=`)
> - Space ()
> - Tab (   )

If a user inputs some string containing any of above listed separators (like `set "id=1 19"` then `%id%` contains a space), then

```
if /i %id%==119 goto Tom
```

results to 

`if /i 1 19==119 goto Tom
       ↑                this space causes error 19==119 was unexpected at this time`

Definitely, you need to escape delimiters and all other `cmd`-poisonous characters  as follows:

```
@echo off
:1
cls
echo Please enter your ID:
set /P id=
if /i "%id%"=="119" goto Tom
if /i "%id%"=="204" goto Brittany
if /i "%id%"=="12"  goto Shannon
if /i "%id%"=="64"  goto Jack
goto 1

rem script continues here
```

FYI, [Redirection article](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lists other `cmd`-poisonous characters which need to be escaped as their unescaped occurrence in a batch script has following meaning:

> - `&`  - *Single Ampersand*: used as a command separator
> - `&&` - *Double Ampersand*: conditional command separator (like `if errorlevel 0`)
> - `||` - *Double Pipe* (Vertical Line): conditional command separator (like `if errorlevel 1`)
> - `|`  - *Single Pipe*: redirects the std.output of one command into the std.input of another
> - `>`  - *Single Greater Than*: redirects output to either a file or file like device
> - `>>` - *Double Greater than*: output will be added to the very end of the file
> - `<`  - *Less Than*: redirect the contents of a file to the std.input of a command

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this! So, when I use quotes, does that mean that it will only go to what I type in?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, try `for %G in ("1<2,64;119") do @for %g in (%~G) do @echo "%g"` from and open `cmd` window to see how to parse multiple user's input. In a batch script, double `%` signs in loop variables `%G` and `%g` as `for %%G in ("1<2,64;119") do for %%g in (%%~G) do echo "%%g"`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand